# 'Unsuported type :hover' and 'Unknown pseudo-class selector :visible'

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, jsdom

I'm not able to use selectors with pseudo classes in a **jsdom** test environment. Is there any trick to do this or some mandatory configuration?

For example, if I do `$("button:hover")` I get the error:

> **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover**

And if I do `document.querySelectorAll("div.testingDivs:not(:visible)")` I get the error:

> **unknown pseudo-class selector ':visible'**

Here is some code with examples: [demo project](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-butterfly-r1tutt?file=/src/App.test.js)

I already notice this problem is related to **nwsapi** plugin. Seems **jsdom** is not registering the pseudo-classes selectors and I think this should be doing in the file `jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\selectors.js`.
In this file the **nwsapi** plugin is only initialized and in the `nwsapi.js` file the selectors are saved in the property `Selectors`. As the **nwsapi** is only initialized without any selector registered, then the `Selectors` are empty all the time and I get the "`unknown pseudo-class selector ':visible'`" error message.

I already tried to do this before the **Jest** test setup:

```
const _nwsapi = require("nwsapi"),
  NW = _nwsapi({
    document: window.document,
    DOMException: global.DOMException
  });

window.NW = {Dom: NW};

require("nwsapi/src/modules/nwsapi-jquery");
```

And almost worked, the `Selectors` were filled with the cases in that file. However, when I use a selector, the **jsdom** initialize the **nwsapi** and the `Selectors` are set to an empty object again.

My project have that kind of selectors inside a component, not inside a test.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Issue opened: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this really helpful link https://levelup.gitconnected.com/when-jsdom-for-testing-ui-its-not-enough-c53a8f8c4638 which says:

> Let’s say you have a Slider component and you want to drag one of the
> handle by some pixels and check that something has changed. You can’t
> really do it in JSDOM. Cause you can’t really drag your handle. The
> same for an infinite scroll component. Or testing pseudo states like
> :hover, :active. You simply can’t. Well. You can…but you should mock
> everything…and sometimes the result it’s not good enough.
>
> The reason why it’s difficult to test such kind of components it’s
> pretty simple: the lack of layouting functionality. JSDOM is a pure
> javascript implementation of the DOM so it’s not even designed to act
> like a real browser. It’s for doing some unit testing. And it’s great
> on doing it, it’s fast. But for some special components we need more.
> We need a real browser. Better if we could have all the three main
> engines :)

I still believe if JSDOM change the file `jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\selectors.js` to something like this, at least the pseudo classes problem will be resolved:

```
function initNwsapi(node) {
  const { _globalObject, _ownerDocument } = node,

  apiResult = nwsapi({
    document: _ownerDocument,
    DOMException: _globalObject.DOMException
  });

  require("nwsapi/src/modules/nwsapi-jquery");

  return apiResult;
}
```

Anyway, some other problems remain.

So I tried to change the selector by removing the pseudo class and search for a class like "`isHovered`". **Remembering that the selector is being used inside a component, not inside a test**.

In some cases, that class exists in another elements not "`:hover`" so I tried to bind a `focus` event and a `mouseover` event to that element and add class like "`thisIsReallyHovered`". But this didn't work well and I also tried to use `document.activeElement` but without greater success.

So like suggested the that article, I searched a bit about other kinds of test environments, like: **Selenium**, **Puppeteer**, **Playwright**, **Cypress**...

I tried to implement **Puppeteer** at my project with **jest**, but I found other problems.

So, since (in my case) the implementation of this kind of test environment is not desirable, we agree to re-think the test to avoid that part of the code, until our code migration be completed and we change that component, implementing only unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

`:hover` is triggered when the mouse (or other pointing device) is pointing at an element. You can't search the DOM for an element the mouse is pointing at in JSDOM because **there is no mouse**!

`:visible` is not a CSS selector. It's a jQuery extension. You aren't using jQuery. You can find everything that matches `div.testingDivs` and then filter it based on the conditions you might have said to cause `:visible` not to match (e.g. testing the height or display) instead.

Comment: So you are saying I can't use testing-library to do things like `fireEvent.mouseOver` because "there is no mouse" in jsdom? Your suggestion for the `:visible` was what I did and what I explained in my post